# React and typescript fortawesome types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have the following interface:

```
export interface IDropdownItems {
  name: string;
  link: string;
}
export interface ITag {
  name: string;
  link: string;
  icon: any;
  dropdownItems: IDropdownItems[] | null;
  active: boolean;
}

export const SideBarTags: ITag[] = [
  {
    name: 'Tutoriais',
    link: '../tutorials',
    icon: faFileAlt,
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Avisos',
    link: '../news',
    icon: faNewspaper,
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Serviços',
    link: '../services',
    icon: faMeteor,
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Elo Boost', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Duo Boost', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'MD10', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Coaching', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'Vitóriais', link: '/duoBoost' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Carteira',
    link: '../cartcredit',
    icon: faWallet,
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Histórico', link: '/history' },
      { name: 'Adicionar Crédito', link: '/add' },
    ],
  },
];
```

But this way I need to import fortawesome twice
I wanted to use a type on my icon

I found the following for typescript:

> const coffeeLookup: IconLookup = { prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'coffee' }
>
> const coffeeIconDefinition: IconDefinition =
>   findIconDefinition(coffeeLookup)

But I'm not able to imagine how I will adapt this to my interface

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood why you needed to import it twice. And are you speeking about fontawesome ?
Did you tried to type your icon as `IconType`, from the react-icon module ?

Comment: I don't know how you get your icon, but in my project i do so :
`import {  faWallet } from "react-icons/fa";`
You can import `import { IconType } from 'react-icons';`
Then you can change your interface to type your icon as :
`icon: TypeIcon`
Of course you need to install the module react-icon.
I don't know if it answer your question ?

Comment: And how would you use this icon?
would you be able to look at my code and try to do as I would?

Comment: Yes, but you have to be more specific on your problem, because i don't understand what it is